# ror deployment with capistrano -> cap:deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, path, capistrano, rvm-capistrano

i've a problem with the deploying.
i have a ubuntu 11.10 server, i have installed ruby 1.9.2 and rails 3.2.6 with RVM.
i have yet made the pull of my git, it's located in /home/******/idepro.git 
i runned the "capify ." command and i modify the deploy.rb file.
i haven't any problem when i run the commands "cap deploy:setup" and "cap deploy:check", but when i run "cap deploy" i have a problem with the enviorment path. The error is:

```
** [out :: 176.58.****] /usr/bin/env: ruby
** [out :: 176.58.****] : No such file or directory
```

these are the ror's path:

```
******@******:~$ which ruby
/home/******/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/ruby
```

and this is the value of $PATH:

```
******@******:~$ echo $PATH
/home/******/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin:/home/******/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/bin:/home/******/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin:/home/******/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/******/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin
```

This is my deploy.rb file:

```
# RVM bootstrap
$:.unshift(File.expand_path('./lib', ENV['rvm_path']))
#require 'rvm/capistrano'
set :rvm_ruby_string, 'ruby1.9.2-p290'

# bundler bootstrap
require 'bundler/capistrano'

# main details
set :application, "176.58.******"
role :web, "176.58.******"
role :app, "176.58.******"
role :db,  "176.58.******", :primary => true

ssh_options[:port] = ******
set :user, "******"
set :password, "******"

# server details
default_run_options[:pty] = true
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true
set :deploy_to, "/var/www/idealarm2"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :user, "passenger"
set :use_sudo, false

# repo details
set :scm, :git
set :scm_username, "passenger"
set :repository, "/home/******/idepro.git"
set :branch, "master"
set :git_enable_submodules, 1

# tasks
namespace :deploy do
    task :start, :roles => :app do
         run "touch #{current_path}/tmp/restart.txt"
    end

    task :stop, :roles => :app do
         # Do nothing.
    end

    desc "Restart Application"
    task :restart, :roles => :app do
         run "touch #{current_path}/tmp/restart.txt"
    end
end

#default_environment['PATH']='/home/******/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin/:/usr/bin:/bin'
#default_environment['GEM_PATH']='/home/******/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320:/home/******/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global:/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.$
```

Could anyone help me with the PATH configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using capistrano with RVM with no issues, having followed the 'Integration via the rvm-capistrano gem' section instructions at https://rvm.io//integration/capistrano/.